# Rspec Class any_instance expects method_name - where it is documented?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I've stumbled upon the following piece of code in an Rspec test and I must say I more or less figured out what it does but I can't find relevant sources to prove it. Please point me to a gem or docs that describe:

```
describe SomeModule::Salesforce::Lead do
  before do
    SomeModule::Salesforce::Lead.any_instance.expects(:materialize)
  end
...
end
```

It seems that for :each example in this spec it sets expectation on any instance of the class described above to receive a call to :materialize method **AND** it actually **redefines** the method to **do nothing** . The last part seems crucial because it avoids connecting to SalesForce in test environment but I can't find confirmation for this.

Answer (score 1):

`any_instance` is documented under [Working with Legacy code](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

You are correct in that it both sets an expectation and stubs out the original method on any given instance of a class.

Previous versions of RSpec accomplish this by monkeypatch the ruby core classes (`Object` and `BaseObject`)

RSpec 3 has a new syntax which does not rely on monkeypatching:

```
before do
  expect_any_instance_of(SomeModule::Salesforce).to receive(:materialize)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've just found that I was looking in wrong sources, it doesn't come from RSpec but from Mocha Mock (expects and any_instance) http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html#expects-instance_method
Thanks @tomasz-pajor @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2928259/tomasz-pajor